# Trigger to enter new record

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a sql to insert records in the notification table 60 days before an employee contract expires.

```
         INSERT INTO notification (name)
    SELECT employee.employee_name
    from EMPLOYEE, employee_info 
    where EMPLOYEE_INFO.EMPLOYEE_NAME(+) =EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME             

AND (LEAVE_TYPE ='Vacation'
             or LEAVE_TYPE = 'Personal')
     group by  EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE.CONTRACT_END_PERIOD, EMPLOYEE.TOTAL_VACATION_LEAVE, EMPLOYEE_INFO.LEAVE_TYPE
      HAVING sum(days_taken) > 0
     and TO_DATE(contract_end_period,'DD-MM-YYYY') < TO_DATE (SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') + 60
);
```

However when  a new employee contracts expires I want only that new record to be inserted into the notification table.

what I am getting presently is the insertion of the old and new entry (because I am using a page load sql) and this is causing duplicates in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO notification (name)
    SELECT employee.employee_name
    from EMPLOYEE, employee_info 
    where EMPLOYEE_INFO.EMPLOYEE_NAME(+) =EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME             
    AND (LEAVE_TYPE ='Vacation' or LEAVE_TYPE = 'Personal')
 -> AND employee.employee_name NOT IN (select notification.name from notification) <-
     group by  EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE.CONTRACT_END_PERIOD, EMPLOYEE.TOTAL_VACATION_LEAVE, EMPLOYEE_INFO.LEAVE_TYPE
      HAVING sum(days_taken) > 0
     and TO_DATE(contract_end_period,'DD-MM-YYYY') < TO_DATE (SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') + 60
);
```

You need limit your query to people who do not yet exist in that table. An example above is given: **"-> AND employee.employee_name NOT IN (select notification.name from notification) <-"** marker.